# What are mix and match attacks? (Docker - snapshot key)

Tags: security, docker

Can someone help me in understanding what are mix and match attacks in security? I tried checking on Google but could not get a clear idea. Any explanation with an example should be helpful

Also, how is this related to do snapshot key in docker content trust?

Answer (score 3):

That expression is used in "[Manage keys for content trust](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/98c245c9e63793cf8ca03c5500e0820447c1861c/docs/security/trust/trust_key_mng.md#manage-keys-for-content-trust)":

> snapshot: This key signs the current collection of image tags, preventing mix and match attacks.
>
> When doing a `docker push` with Content Trust enabled for the first time, the root, targets, snapshot, and timestamp keys are generated automatically for the image repository:
>   The timestamp and snapshot keys are safely generated and stored in a signing server that is deployed alongside the Docker registry. These keys are generated in a backend service that isn't directly exposed to the internet and are encrypted at rest.

That is part of the [docker notary architecture](https://github.com/docker/notary/blob/master/docs/service_architecture.md):

> **Rollback, Freeze, Mix and Match** - The attacker can request that the Notary signer sign any arbitrary timestamp (and maybe snapshot) metadata they want. Attackers can launch a freeze attack, and, depending on whether the snapshot key is available, a mix-and-match attack up to the expiration of the targets file.
>
> Clients both with and without pinned trust would be vulnerable to these attacks, so long as the attacker ensures that the version number of their malicious metadata is higher than the version number of the most recent good metadata that any client may have.
>
> Note that the timestamp and snapshot keys cannot be compromised in a server-only compromise, so a key rotation would not be necessary. Once the Server compromise is mitigated, an attacker will not be able to generate valid timestamp or snapshot metadata and serve them on a malicious mirror, for example.
>
> **An attacker can add malicious content, remove legitimate content from a collection, and mix up the targets in a collection**, but only within the particular delegation roles that the key can sign for.

For a definition of those terms, one can look at "[Improving Hackage security](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/2015/04/improving-hackage-security/#attacks)" (for Haskell, but it applies also for a Docker registry):

> - **Rollback attacks** where an attacker gets a client to install an older version of a package than a version the client previously knew about.
>     Consider for example a case where the older package might have known security vulnerabilities.
> - **Freeze attacks** where the attacker prevents the entire set of packages from being updated (e.g. by always responding with an old snapshot).
> - **Mix and match attacks** where the attacker supplies combinations of packages or package metadata that never existed in the upstream repository.